# Android - Erro com setContentView(R.layout.Principal);

Tags: android, android-studio

Boa tarde,

Estou tendo problemas com setContent ele informa o seguinte erro: Cannot resolve symbol 'Principal'

Esse está ocorrendo no ->

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Esse arquivo 'Principal' está em: app -> res -> layout -> Principal.xml

**Tools.java**

```
    package view;

public class Tools extends Activity {

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Principal);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */

    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    public void call_Desligar(View tools) {

        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "reboot -p"});
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void call_Reiniciar(View tools) {

        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "reboot"});
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void call_Sair(View tools) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Eu acredito que o nome do seu layout não pode ser Principal com letras maisculas, tenta refatorar ele pra *layout_principal*

Comment: Certo, volto já.

Comment: Infelizmente não resolveu. Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto pode estar acontecendo por dois motivos:

**1.  Uppercase**

> Esta propriedade deve conter apenas caracteres com letras minúsculas. 
>   Ao tentar rodar a aplicação ocorrerá o seguinte erro: Erro: 'P' não é
>   um caractere de nome de recurso com base em arquivo válido: os nomes
>   de recursos baseados em arquivos devem conter apenas Minúsculas az,
>   0-9 ou sublinhado /

**2. Verifique seus import's**

Exitem várias classes `R` em um projeto android!

Exemplo:

```
// referente a biblioteca recyclerview 
 android.support.v7.recyclerview.R;
// referente a biblioteca Support Design 
  android.support.design.R;
// referente a biblioteca CardView 
  android.support.v7.cardview.R;
```

Para que importe os itens referente ao seu projeto, é necessário importar a do projeto!

Para identificar, verifique o pacote de onde esta classe `R` vem!

No seu caso, deverá ser igual ao pacote do seu projeto.

Segue um exemplo:

```
import seu.projeto.R;
```

Comment: Esse import está adicionado já. Mais mesmo assim não resolveu :(

Comment: Corrigi a resposta! deixe a nome do arquivo **Principal.xml** como **principal.xml**

Comment: E **setContentView(R.layout.Principal);** como **setContentView(R.layout.principal);**

Comment: Obrigado campeão!

Comment: Outra coisa, marque como correta a resposta, apenas se ela lhe ajudou ou foi útil! [Sugiro esta leitura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)